# Why multiple parallel webdriver instances in Windows are sharing one chrome window, but not in Linux?

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, junit5

We are using Junit5 + Selenium/Webdriver to run parallel tests.

junit-platform.properties has this settings:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor = 1.5
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = dynamic
```

The Test*.java:

```
public class TestSuiteParallel extends TestSuite {

  @RepeatedTest(2)
  void testParallel() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
    driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Running in Linux everything works perfect, we have multiple Chromium windows handled separately by each thread worker. Headless or not, it works.

Running in Windows, always only ONE Chrome window with multiple tabs is openend. And only the last openend tab (in foreground) works sometimes. Mostly all tabs are frozen, nothing happens, after some seconds we get `WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed`

If I change the code to `@RepeatedTest(1)` it runs without errors as expected.

So why this works so differently? Is there a setting I can force WebDriver to always open separate Browser windows? Or maybe it's more an operation system setting?

Comment: Is your [test instance lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle) per method or class? `driver` appears to be a mutable field, this can cause trouble in a concurrent environment. Could you try to make `driver` a local variable, just to see if the behavior changes? It might be helpful if you could include more code to form an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also from your base class.

Comment: Thanks for your questions. I changed my code above slightly to have an MWE .. with the above described behavior. So far I understand it's a 'per method' lifecycle.